# Searching through a series of sets

Tags: java, collections

I don't know if this question has been asked before but I tried to find answers before posting, but no luck.

I have four objects let's say floor, fridge, bowl, and apple. Fridges, bowls, and apples are added as needed.
Each apple has an expiration date.
Floor holds a `set<Fridge>`, fridge holds a `set<bowl>` and bowl holds a `set<apple>`.
When I add an apple to the set I would like to retrieve the last apple added before.
I tried the following code but it does not help as it returns false all the time.

```
public boolean previousAppleExist(Date aDate){
    boolean found = false;
    Date previousDay = new Date(aDate.aPreviousDate(aDate)); //returns a day before
    String expiryDate = previousDay.getDate();//returns a String in format dd/mm/yyyy
    for(Fridge fridge: fridgeSet ){
        if (this.fridgeExist(expiryDate)){
            for (Bowl bowl: bowlSet){
                if (this.existingFridge(expiryDate).bowlExist(expiryDate)){
                    for(Apple apple: appleSet){
                        if(this.existingFridge(expiryDate).
                           existingBowl(expiryDate).appleExist(expiryDate)){
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            previousDay = new Date(previousDay.
                                          aPreviousDate(previousDay));
                            startDate = previousDay.getDate();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    previousDay = new Date(previousDay.
                                  aPreviousDate(previousDay));
                    expiryDate = previousDay.getDate();
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            previousDay = new Date(previousDay.aPreviousDate(previousDay));
            expiryDate = previousDay.getDate();
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: It returns false every time.

Comment: Are u sure u meant to use result = true? Also, are u sure your break statement is in the correct space

Comment: Sorry typo. I meant the boolean found needs to be set to true, will edit it straight away. Also, I need it to stop when the apple is found, that's why the break statement is there.